# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'PH'

Tags: vb.net

I get this error and am a bit new to vb.net and sql so i'm not really sure what it means... heres the code above this.

```
Private Sub loadReports()
    Dim drReport As SqlDataReader, cnPHCS As SqlConnection
    Dim sJobNo As String, sClient As String, sLastClient As String = ""
    Dim sDate As String, iMovement As Integer
    Dim sClientWhere As String = 0, nTotalKm As Double = 0, nTotal As Double = 0
    Dim sFrom As String, sType As String
    Dim nDayAmount As Double = 0, nDayKm As Double = 0, nDayHours As Double = 0, nDrivers As Double = 0
    Dim nDrCost As Double = 0, nKmCost As Double = 0, nOthCost As Double = 0, nDrTotal As Double = 0, nKmTotal As Double = 0, nOthTotal As Double = 0, nMvmtDrCost As Double = 0
    Dim nMargin As Double = 0, nExtras As Double = 0, nCosts As Double = 0, iMovementTotal As Double = 0
    Dim iJobCount As Integer = 0

    If sClientID <> "(all)" And sClientID <> "" Then sClientWhere = "PH.ClientID = '" & sClientID & "' AND "

    sSql = "SELECT PH.PrivateHireID, PH.BookingType, PHM.PrivateHireMovementID, PH.ClientID, PHM.StartDateTime, PHM.PickupDateTime, PHM.Pickup, PHM.PickupInstructions, PHM.SingleJourney, PHM.Destination, PHM.DestinationInstructions, PHM.ArrivalDateTime, PHM.LeaveDateTime, PHM.BackDateTime, " & _
     "PHM.FinishDateTime, SUM(PHV.Total) AS Total, COUNT(PHV.VehicleID) AS Vehicles, C.Company, PH.Price AS JobPrice, PH.Total AS JobTotal, PH.Invoice AS JobInvoice, " & _
     "(SELECT SUM(Total) AS Extras FROM PrivateHireExtras WHERE PrivateHireMovementID = PHM.PrivateHireMovementID) AS ExtrasTotal " & _
     "FROM [PrivateHires] PH INNER JOIN (PrivateHireMovements PHM INNER JOIN PrivateHireVehicles PHV ON PHM.PrivateHireMovementID = PHV.PrivateHireMovementID) ON PH.PrivateHireID = PHM.PrivateHireID " & _
     "INNER JOIN Clients C ON PH.ClientID = C.ClientID " & _
     "WHERE " & sClientWhere & "PH.Cancelled=0 AND PHM.Cancelled = 0 AND PHM.PickupDateTime >= '" & calendarFrom.SelectedDate & "' AND PHM.PickupDateTime < '" & calendarTo.SelectedDate & "' AND NOT (PH.BookingType IN ('SPONSOR','HD SCHOOL')) " & _
     "GROUP BY PH.PrivateHireID, PH.BookingType, PHM.PrivateHireMovementID, PH.ClientID, PHM.StartDateTime, PHM.PickupDateTime, PHM.Pickup, PHM.PickupInstructions, PHM.SingleJourney, PHM.Destination, PHM.DestinationInstructions, PHM.ArrivalDateTime, PHM.LeaveDateTime, PHM.BackDateTime, PHM.FinishDateTime, C.Company, PH.Price, PH.Total, PH.Invoice " & _
      "ORDER BY PH.PrivateHireID, PHM.PickupDateTime, PHM.PrivateHireMovementID "

    cnPHCS = New SqlConnection(DBCONN_STR)
    cnPHCS.Open()
    drReport = New SqlCommand(sSql, cnPHCS).ExecuteReader

    Dim dtData As Data.DataTable, drRow As Data.DataRow

    dtData = New Data.DataTable
    dtData = makeReportTable()
    Do While drReport.Read
        iMovement = iMovement + 1
```

Comment: If your question is about the SQL, then all of the extraneous code is irrelevant. Show a messagebox containing your SQL after it's built, or put it into a text control where you can copy it, paste it in to an SQL tool for your database, and try to execute it. It's clear there's a syntax error in the mess you dumped here, but with all of the string concatenation, variables involved, and the long statement with all of the "", "'", and other noise it's difficult to see what it might be. You can set a breakpoint at the `cnPHCS` line that follows and see it in its entirety much more easily.

Comment: It would help if you post your schema, especially the PrivateHires table which seems to be the problem.

Comment: Put Option Strict On at the top of your code or set it in the project's properties.  What happens if `sClientID = "(all)"`?  In that case you are not setting the value of sClientWhere so it just has the value of "0" which makes your SQL statement invalid.  Also you should do a search for the term 'Sql Injection'.  Your code is vulnerable to that attack.